# Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records (Simple 1 row table with 4 columns in Windows forms)

Tags: c#, sqlite, concurrency, datatable

I have a one-row table with some identity values for an installation. It has a primary key column (value=1) and three other columns.

On initial app startup I am updating the three columns with new values. 
But then on update, I get the above error.

The data is not bound to form controls - it's all in the code below.

I've tried dropping the PK, but then I can't use the SQL builder.

I've added the PK column that never changes, rather than using the first data column as the PK.

I've also tried banging my head against a brick wall, but that didn't work either!

```
SQLiteConnection cnWLLocal = new SQLiteConnection(); 
cnWLData.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WordLightData.sqlite; Version = 3; DateTimeFormat=CurrentCulture ;"; 

string s = "Select Key, WLIdentity, WLIdentityCode, LastSongDBCheck from LocalInfo";
cmdLocalInfo = new SQLiteCommand(s, cnWLLocal);
daLocalInfo = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdLocalInfo);
dsLocalInfo = new DataSet();
daLocalInfo.Fill(dsLocalInfo, "LocalInfo");    // BTW this works perfectly - data is returned
bldLocalInfo = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(daLocalInfo);

dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].Rows[0]["WLIdentity"] = "New value";
dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].Rows[0]["WLIdentityCode"] = "New value";
dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].Rows[0]["LastSongDBCheck"] = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

DataSet dsChanges = new DataSet();
dsChanges = dsLocalInfo.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
if (dsChanges != null)
{
daLocalInfo.UpdateCommand = bldLocalInfo.GetUpdateCommand();
int iRowsUpdated = daLocalInfo.Update(dsChanges, “LocalInfo”);
}
```

The table is defined in SQLite as:

Key - Integer PK

WLIdentity - String (20)

WLIdentityCode - Text (15)

LastSongDBCheck - Integer (8)

Comment: I have solved this immediate problem - two of the columns had no data and so were null (I think). I entered some dummy data into those columns from the backend, then no longer got this error.
But I'd still like to know how to solve this problem!?

Comment: That is a rather cumbersome way to handle/store a DateTime.  A plain DateTime column wouldnt require any gyrations from string to int and back (and then to date presumably)

Comment: Thanks - I'm just using the yyyymmdd to do a comparison with a saved value. The date time is just a convenient test and I don't need the complications of date/time formats.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code :

```
        var cnWLLocal = new SQLiteConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=WordLightData.sqlite; Version = 3; DateTimeFormat=CurrentCulture ;"
        };


        const string s = "Select Key, WLIdentity, WLIdentityCode, LastSongDBCheck from LocalInfo";

        using (var cmdLocalInfo = new SQLiteCommand(s, cnWLLocal))
        {
            using (var daLocalInfo = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmdLocalInfo))
            {
                using (var dsLocalInfo = new DataSet())
                {
                    daLocalInfo.Fill(dsLocalInfo, "LocalInfo");    // BTW this works perfectly - data is returned

                    using (var bldLocalInfo = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(daLocalInfo))
                    {
                        dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].Rows[0]["WLIdentity"] = "New value";
                        dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].Rows[0]["WLIdentityCode"] = "New value";
                        dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].Rows[0]["LastSongDBCheck"] = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

                        using (DataTable tableChanges = dsLocalInfo.Tables["LocalInfo"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified))
                        {
                            if (tableChanges != null)
                            {
                                daLocalInfo.UpdateCommand = bldLocalInfo.GetUpdateCommand();

                                int iRowsUpdated = daLocalInfo.Update(tableChanges);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's different about this technique? It just seems to be saying only update the table if there's changes, and there must be changes from the middle three lines. Is the daLocalInfo.UpdateCommand = bldLocalInfo.GetUpdateCommand() going to be different within the using section? Tks

Comment: this line SQLiteConnection cnWLLocal = new SQLiteConnection(); 
cnWLData.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WordLightData.sqlite; Version = 3; DateTimeFormat=CurrentCulture ;";

Comment: Ah yes - thanks. I did already have that, but didn't include it in my sample. Thanks for the suggestion.